# Discord.py bot will not react to it's own message. How can i do this?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im trying to get my bot to react with an emoji to its own embed, i have the code written out but the bot does not react with the emoji. How can i fix this? Thanks

```
@bot.command()
async def emoji(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Test", description="Test", color=0x00FFFF)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  msg = await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel,embed=embed)
  await bot.add_reaction(msg, "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using

```
await botMessage.add_reaction("")
```

for example.

```
@bot.command()
async def emoji(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title = "Test", description = "Test", color = 0x00FFFF)
  msg = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
  await msg.add_reaction("")
```